# HTML code with curly braces

Tags: html

I have recently seen one HTML page.The code is embed with curly braces.Values for tags and loops are closed by curly braces.

```
            {% if authenticated %}
            <h1>Current User</h1>
            <p>{{user}}</p>
            {% else %}
            <h1>Current User</h1>
            <p>None</p>
            {% endif %}
```

What is the actaul use of these type of code?

Is HTML embedded with any other language?

Comment: It's a templating system like Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279240/curly-brackets-in-html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What dose the curly-brace and percent sign mean in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887579/what-dose-the-curly-brace-and-percent-sign-mean-in-html)

Comment: It might be Django as well... You see the server side code, this page is generated per request and the client doesn't see these

Answer (score 3):

This may be Django script templates. Find more [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the HTML is enriched with [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or a similar templating engine.

It's used for displaying JavaScript data in your HTML without the need to know how JavaScript works.