# substitute string with another string in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In the view.py I have a list like this:

```
context['cities'] = ['London', 'Beijing', 'Cape Town', ..]
```

I don't know why I can't substitute substring in string in the following `Html` code:

```
{% for city in cities % }
  <di style="background-image: url({% static 'app/img/{{city}}.jpg' %});">
{% endfor %}
```

I expect something like `app/img/London.jpg`.

in *inspect* what I see is this string:

```
url(/static/app/img/%7B%7Bcity%7D%7D.jpg);
```

Comment: It looks like you are using a Python web server that reads template HTML files and inserts text in them before sending them out. What server is that? Flask? Django? Something else? In other words, what libraries do you import in your main Python file?

Comment: I updated the tags. I am using django, and this is django template,

Comment: Tagging django should help. You may also find some info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/ . It looks like they usually leave blank spaces just inside the curly brackets in those template files. Maybe that would help?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had a look to this doc before, I also tried `{% cycle static 'app/img/{{city}}.jpg' %}` however didn't work. Not sure if this is the right approach

Comment: Does `{% cycle static 'app/img/{{ city }}.jpg' %}` or `{% cycle static {{ 'app/img/{}.jpg'.format(city) }} %} ` work any better? I don't use django so I'd have to read the docs to suggest anything more.

Comment: No, unfortunately none of them work. Django template does not support python `.format()`

Comment: How about `<di style="background-image: url('app/img/{% {{ city }} %}.jpg');">`?

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Thanks, I solved by using this string `"/static/app/img/top-cities/{{ city }}.jpg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve problem with just a bit editing my code:

```
{% for city in cities % }
  <di style="background-image: url("/static/app/img/top-cities/{{ city }}.jpg">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

In python, `{{`, `}}` stands for normal curly braces, not for putting a value within them.

So `{{city}}` doesn't return the value of the city variable, it returns `{city}`.

The double braces for returning a literal brace is complicated and doesn't make as much sense as `\{`, but it is what it is.

Comment: Here's the link to the official python docs for this: [stupid double curly braces make no sense](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I didn't understand, you mean it should be written like `app/img/cities/\{{city}}.jpg` in html?

Comment: my question is about html, python was example. let me update

Comment: Ahhh I see. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717081/html-code-with-curly-braces) then.

Comment: unfortunately could't find any straight forward solution for my question.